# TEXINPUTS equivalent for inputminted to make relative paths work?

Tags: minted, paths, environment-variables

A while ago I griped about LaTeX not supporting relative paths by default. It turns out I can export the `TEXINPUTS=/path/to/source` environment variable to make `\input{foo}` look in `/path/to/source/foo`.

Now when I try to do an out-of-source compile of my document, `\input` picks up relative paths correctly but `\inputminted` can't find the files by relative paths.

To clarify, suppose I have these files

```
main.tex
chapters/ch1.tex
examples/foo.c
```

If main.tex contains

```
\input{chapters/ch1.tex}
\inputminted[linenos]{c}{examples/foo.c}
```

Then I do

```
mkdir /tmp/buildtex
cd /tmp/buildtex
TEXTINPUTS=/path/to/source pdflatex /path/to/source/main.tex
```

Then `\input` finds its file but `\inputminted` does not.

How to bring inputminted into agreement?

Comment: Try `\usepackage[kpsewhich]{minted}`.

Comment: Any news here? Have you tried the suggestion by Imieee?

Comment: @Imieee Doesn't work for me, lualatex just hang. I'm trying to `\inputminted{xml}{../assets/code.xml}`

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/251#issuecomment-586551687